# yield in list comprehensions and generator expressions

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension, yield, generator-expression

The following behaviour seems rather counterintuitive to me (Python 3.4):

```
>>> [(yield i) for i in range(3)]
<generator object <listcomp> at 0x0245C148>
>>> list([(yield i) for i in range(3)])
[0, 1, 2]
>>> list((yield i) for i in range(3))
[0, None, 1, None, 2, None]
```

The intermediate values of the last line are actually not always `None`, they are whatever we `send` into the generator, equivalent (I guess) to the following generator:

```
def f():
   for i in range(3):
      yield (yield i)
```

It strikes me as funny that those three lines work at all. The [Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) says that `yield` is only allowed in a function definition (though I may be reading it wrong and/or it may simply have been copied from the older version). The first two lines produce a `SyntaxError` in Python 2.7, but the third line doesn't.

Also, it seems odd

- that a list comprehension returns a generator and not a list
- and that the generator expression converted to a list and the corresponding list comprehension contain different values.

Could someone provide more information?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

> **Note**: this was a bug in the CPython's handling of `yield` in comprehensions and generator expressions, fixed in Python 3.8, with a deprecation warning in Python 3.7. See the [Python bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue10544) and the *What's New* entries for [Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.7.html#deprecated) and [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.8.html#changes-in-python-behavior).

Generator expressions, and set and dict comprehensions are compiled to (generator) function objects. In Python 3, list comprehensions get the same treatment; they are all, in essence, a new nested scope.

You can see this if you try to disassemble a generator expression:

```
>>> dis.dis(compile("(i for i in range(3))", '', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <genexpr> at 0x10f7530c0, file "", line 1>)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<genexpr>')
              6 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              9 LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             18 GET_ITER
             19 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             22 POP_TOP
             23 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(compile("(i for i in range(3))", '', 'exec').co_consts[0])
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    3 FOR_ITER                11 (to 17)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
              9 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             12 YIELD_VALUE
             13 POP_TOP
             14 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
        >>   17 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

The above shows that a generator expression is compiled to a code object, loaded as a function (`MAKE_FUNCTION` creates the function object from the code object). The `.co_consts[0]` reference lets us see the code object generated for the expression, and it uses `YIELD_VALUE` just like a generator function would.

As such, the `yield` expression works in that context, as the compiler sees these as functions-in-disguise.

This is a bug; `yield` has no place in these expressions. The Python *grammar* before Python 3.7 allows it (which is why the code is compilable), but the [`yield` expression specification](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) shows that using `yield` here should not actually work:

> The yield expression is only used when defining a *generator* function and thus can only be used in the body of a function definition.

This has been confirmed to be a bug in [issue 10544](http://bugs.python.org/issue10544). The resolution of the bug is that using `yield` and `yield from` will [raise a `SyntaxError` in Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#changes-in-python-behavior); in Python 3.7 [it raises a `DeprecationWarning`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html#deprecated) to ensure code stops using this construct. You'll see the same warning in Python 2.7.15 and up if you use the [`-3` command line switch](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-3) enabling Python 3 compatibility warnings.

The 3.7.0b1 warning looks like this; turning warnings into errors gives you a `SyntaxError` exception, like you would in 3.8:

```
>>> [(yield i) for i in range(3)]
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: 'yield' inside list comprehension
<generator object <listcomp> at 0x1092ec7c8>
>>> import warnings
>>> warnings.simplefilter('error')
>>> [(yield i) for i in range(3)]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: 'yield' inside list comprehension
```

The differences between how `yield` in a list comprehension and `yield` in a generator expression operate stem from the differences in how these two expressions are implemented. In Python 3 a list comprehension uses `LIST_APPEND` calls to add the top of the stack to the list being built, while a generator expression instead yields that value. Adding in `(yield <expr>)` just adds another `YIELD_VALUE` opcode to either:

```
>>> dis.dis(compile("[(yield i) for i in range(3)]", '', 'exec').co_consts[0])
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    6 FOR_ITER                13 (to 22)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
             12 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             15 YIELD_VALUE
             16 LIST_APPEND              2
             19 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6
        >>   22 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(compile("((yield i) for i in range(3))", '', 'exec').co_consts[0])
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    3 FOR_ITER                12 (to 18)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
              9 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             12 YIELD_VALUE
             13 YIELD_VALUE
             14 POP_TOP
             15 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
        >>   18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             21 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `YIELD_VALUE` opcode at bytecode indexes 15 and 12 respectively is extra, a cuckoo in the nest. So for the list-comprehension-turned-generator you have 1 yield producing the top of the stack each time (replacing the top of the stack with the `yield` return value), and for the generator expression variant you yield the top of the stack (the integer) and then yield *again*, but now the stack contains the return value of the `yield` and you get `None` that second time.

For the list comprehension then, the intended `list` object output is still returned, but Python 3 sees this as a generator so the return value is instead attached to the [`StopIteration` exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration) as the `value` attribute:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> listgen = [(yield i) for i in range(3)]
>>> list(islice(listgen, 3))  # avoid exhausting the generator
[0, 1, 2]
>>> try:
...     next(listgen)
... except StopIteration as si:
...     print(si.value)
... 
[None, None, None]
```

Those `None` objects are the return values from the `yield` expressions.

And to reiterate this again; this same issue applies to dictionary and set comprehension in Python 2 and Python 3 as well; in Python 2 the `yield` return values are still added to the intended dictionary or set object, and the return value is 'yielded' last instead of attached to the `StopIteration` exception:

```
>>> list({(yield k): (yield v) for k, v in {'foo': 'bar', 'spam': 'eggs'}.items()})
['bar', 'foo', 'eggs', 'spam', {None: None}]
>>> list({(yield i) for i in range(3)})
[0, 1, 2, set([None])]
```

Comment: Note that according to the language specification the `yield-atom` is allowed inside an expression (inside a generator function). This could be even more problematic if the `yield-atom` is somehow misimplemented.

Comment: @skyking: that's what I'm saying; the grammar allows it. The bug I refer to is trying to use a `yield` *as part of a generator expression inside a generator function*, where the expectation is that the `yield` applies to the generator function, not the generator expression nested scope.

Comment: Wow. Very informative indeed. So, if I understood correctly, the following happened: a function that contains both `yield` and `return` should, as is documented, become a generator function whose `return`ed value should land in the `StopIteration` exception, and the bytecode for a list comprehension with `yield` inside looks (although it was not intended) just like the bytecode of such a function.

Comment: @zabolekar: something like that; the steps are something like: the compiler comes across a list comprehension so builds a code object; the compiler comes across a `yield` expression so marks the current code object as a generator. Voila, we have a generator function.

Comment: and your last comment also explains the other oddity here: `[(yield i) for i in range(3)]` returns a `<generator object at ....>` instead of a list. Quirky.

Comment: This answer could do with an update, see the more recent discussion on the bug report https://bugs.python.org/issue10544; this syntax will sometimes raise a `DeprecationWarning` in Py 3.7 and then a `SyntaxError` from Py 3.8 https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html#deprecated I was going to post something myself but I think Martijn would do a much better job explaining all this!

Comment: Best quote from the bug report: "I think we all need to calm down a bit. How about not posting about this topic for 24 hours." - Guido

Comment: @Chris_Rands: thanks for the heads-up! I noticed that the implementation of the deprecation warning was accidentally committed to the 2.7 branch though.

Comment: It's a mistake rather than backported is it? Also seems that even for Py 3.7+ `yield` is still  allowed in the outer iterator for `[func(x, y) for x in <outermost iterator> for y in <something else>]` Guido says

Comment: @Chris_Rands no, I misread the commit info attached to the bug report; I forgot 3.7 was still the master branch when the first patch landed.

Comment: @Chris_Rands the 2.7 changes are there for when you use the `-3` compatibility warnings.