# Why "yield from" does not work as expected in all() or any()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Today I was debugging a strange issue. The program is complex, but I have simplified the part in question to just few lines reproducing the strange behaviour.

In the example I test a random generator three times in a row. If all three tests return True, the test is completed. If not, the test must be repeated from the beginning.

Function `func1` works OK. Function `func2` with `any()` should be equivalent to `func1`, but it isn't. It does not work, it produces an error. The `func3` is broken as well, this one is an infinite busy loop.

Where is the problem? It is legal to use `yield from` in other ways than `value = yield from ...` ? I did not found anything in the docs (so far):

> When yield from  is used, it treats the supplied expression as a
>   subiterator. All values produced by that subiterator are passed
>   directly to the caller of the current generator’s methods.

---

```
# Python 3.3 or newer
import random

def yield_random():
    if random.choice((True, False)):
        yield "OK"
        return True
    return False

def func1():
    # only this function works fine
    ok3 = False
    while not ok3:
        for i in range(3):
            ok1 = yield from yield_random()
            if not ok1:
                print("-- not ok")
                break
        else:
            print("All 3 ok !")
            ok3 = True

def func2():
    # does not work
    ok3 = False
    while not ok3:
        ok3 = all((yield from yield_random()) for i in range(3))
    print("All 3 ok !")

def func3():
    # does not work
    while any(not (yield from yield_random()) for i in range(3)):
        print("-- not ok")
    print("All 3 ok !")

for x in func1():
    print("got:", x)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This code doesn't make much sense. Why are you using generator to generate single value?

Comment: `yield "OK"; return True` that is strange.

Comment: As I wrote, this is a simplification derived from much more complex code. It simply does not makes sense in this form. In reality the generator is a coroutine and the yielded values are asynchronous operations to be performed by a special library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`func1` is a function returning a generator while `func2` and `func3` are regular functions:

```
>>> type(func1())
<class 'generator'>
>>> type(func2())
All 3 ok !
<class 'NoneType'>
```

That's because:

```
ok3 = all((yield from yield_random()) for i in range(3))
```

is actually equivalent to:

```
def _gen():
    for i in range(3):
        r = yield from yield_random()
        yield r
ok3 = all(_gen())
```

This code doesn't yield anything since the `yield from` statement is encapsulated in a generator. You can even run it outside of a function, in your console for instance:

```
>>> all((yield from yield_random()) for i in range(3))
False
```

Though it probably doesn't do what you expect:

```
>>> list((yield from yield_random()) for i in range(3))
['OK', True, False, False]
```

Comment: all should not be used with side effects anyway

Comment: @Vincent: that's a fine explanation of what is actually happenning. Do you think it is in accordance with docs?  _any function containing a yield keyword is a generator function_.

Comment: @VPfB I agree this is a bit tricky, but you wouldn't expect a function that defines an inner generator to be a generator itself. And it gets even trickier if you use `yield` inside a list comprehension, see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139885/yield-in-list-comprehensions-and-generator-expressions).

Comment: @Vincent: Interesting reading, I mean that thread including the links in it. So the main point is that nested scopes are silently created in a function. You said that using yield inside comprehensions (and generator expressions) is "tricky". I woud rather use the word "gotcha". Anyway, your helpful answer is accepted, many thanks.