# Why does adding parenthesis around a yield call in a generator allow it to compile/run?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado, coroutine

I have a method:

```
@gen.coroutine
def my_func(x):
    return 2 * x
```

basically, a tornado coroutine.

I am making a list such as:

```
my_funcs = []
for x in range(0, 10):
    f = yield my_func(x)
    my_funcs.append(x)
```

In trying to make this a list comprehension such as:

```
my_funcs = [yield my_func(i) for i in range(0,10)]
```

I realized this was invalid syntax. It [turns out you can do this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/33540588#33540588) using `()` around the yield:

```
my_funcs = [(yield my_func(i)) for i in range(0,10)]
```

- Does this behavior (the syntax for wrapping a `yield foo()` call in () such as `(yield foo() )` in order to allow this above code to execute) have a specific type of name?
- Is it some form of operator precedence with `yield`?
- Is this behavior with `yield` documented somewhere?

Python 2.7.11 on OSX. This code does need to work in both Python2/3 which is why the above list comprehension is not a good idea (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32139977/1048539) for why, the above list comp works in Python 2.7 but is broken in Python 3).

Comment: Because of operator precedence.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but `yield` is [not in the Python2 docs under operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) - code like `m = [foobar() for i in range(0, 10)]` works fine and as expected.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I added an example of why I ended up with list comprehension in the first place.

Comment: Are you trying to end up with a list or a generator?

Comment: @enderland: which is definitely an oversight, because just like `lambda`, `yield` is an expression atom and has a precedence. It looks like it has a lower precedence even than `lambda`.

Comment: Not sure how you end up with None, are you returning the list in a function?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: In Python 3, a list comp is given a new scope (a hidden function basically), using `yield` in it produces a generator function, and because nothing is sending anything to the generator, every `yield` expression defaults to producing `None`. This is a know issue with using `yield` in generator expressions and the other comprehensions, as well as list comps in Python 3.

Comment: Side note: *don't use a list comp* for the side effects. You are now building a very expensive and useless list of `None` references.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am not planning on using list comprehension here due to those issues (which are discussed elsewhere here). But my curiosity about _why_ got me going down the rabbit trail, so to speak ;-)

Comment: "While this compiles and runs, it adds None into it because of how yield works in list comprehension." - at least on Python 2, putting the `yield` inside a list comprehension shouldn't have had such effect. It would have had a different, even crazier effect in Python 3, or with something like a dict or set comprehension, but not a Python 2 list comprehension.

Comment: @user2357112 I just removed that part of the question, I'm more curious about the `()` than the actual explanation for the generator/yield stuff. That is discussed [elsewhere in depth](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32139977/1048539).

Comment: @MartijnPieters but why does it result in *alternating* values and None? for example: `list((yield i) for i in range(2))` results in `[0, None, 1, None]`. I guess it's time for me to finally read PEP 342...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139885/yield-in-list-comprehensions-and-generator-expressions/32139977#32139977). Incidentally, this code does need to work in both Python2.7 and Python3, so I'm most _definitely_ not going to try to use a list comp to create this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters,  but the OP is using python2?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: yeah, the claim was puzzling, and I don't have the time and energy right now to reproduce what happens here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`yield` expressions must be parenthesized in any context except as an entire statement or as the right-hand side of an assignment:

```
# If your code doesn't look like this, you need parentheses:
yield x
y = yield x
```

This is stated in the [PEP that introduced `yield` expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/) (as opposed to `yield` statements), and it's implied by the contexts in which `yield_expr` appears in the [grammar](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html), although no one is expecting you to read the grammar:

> A yield-expression must always be parenthesized except when it
>       occurs at the top-level expression on the right-hand side of an
>       assignment.