# Differences between generator comprehension expressions

Tags: python, generator, generator-expression

There are, as far as I know, three ways to create a generator through a comprehension<sup>1</sup>.

The classical one:

```
def f1():
    g = (i for i in range(10))
```

The `yield` variant:

```
def f2():
    g = [(yield i) for i in range(10)]
```

The `yield from` variant (that raises a `SyntaxError` except inside of a function):

```
def f3():
    g = [(yield from range(10))]
```

The three variants lead to different bytecode, which is not really surprising.
It would seem logical that the first one is the best, since it's a dedicated, straightforward syntax to create a generator through comprehension.
However, it is not the one that produces the shortest bytecode.

*Disassembled in Python 3.6*

**Classical generator comprehension**

```
>>> dis.dis(f1)
4           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <genexpr> at...>)
            2 LOAD_CONST               2 ('f1.<locals>.<genexpr>')
            4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
            6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
            8 LOAD_CONST               3 (10)
           10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
           12 GET_ITER
           14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
           16 STORE_FAST               0 (g)

5          18 LOAD_FAST                0 (g)
           20 RETURN_VALUE
```

**`yield` variant**

```
>>> dis.dis(f2)
8           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <listcomp> at...>)
            2 LOAD_CONST               2 ('f2.<locals>.<listcomp>')
            4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
            6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
            8 LOAD_CONST               3 (10)
           10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
           12 GET_ITER
           14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
           16 STORE_FAST               0 (g)

9          18 LOAD_FAST                0 (g)
           20 RETURN_VALUE
```

**`yield from` variant**

```
>>> dis.dis(f3)
12           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
             2 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
             4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             6 GET_YIELD_FROM_ITER
             8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            10 YIELD_FROM
            12 BUILD_LIST               1
            14 STORE_FAST               0 (g)

13          16 LOAD_FAST                0 (g)
            18 RETURN_VALUE
```

---

In addition, a `timeit` comparison shows that the `yield from` variant is the fastest (still run with Python 3.6):

```
>>> timeit(f1)
0.5334039637357152

>>> timeit(f2)
0.5358906506760719

>>> timeit(f3)
0.19329123352712596
```

`f3` is more or less 2.7 times as fast as `f1` and `f2`.

As **Leon** mentioned in a comment, the efficiency of a generator is best measured by the speed it can be iterated over.
So I changed the three functions so they iterate over the generators, and call a dummy function.

```
def f():
    pass

def fn():
    g = ...
    for _ in g:
        f()
```

The results are even more blatant:

```
>>> timeit(f1)
1.6017412817975778

>>> timeit(f2)
1.778684261368946

>>> timeit(f3)
0.1960603619517669
```

`f3` is now 8.4 times as fast as `f1`, and 9.3 times as fast as `f2`.

**Note:** The results are more or less the same when the iterable is not `range(10)` but a static iterable, such as `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.
Therefore, the difference of speed has nothing to do with `range` being somehow optimized.

---

So, what are the differences between the three ways?
More specifically, what is the difference between the `yield from` variant and the two other?

Is this normal behaviour that the natural construct `(elt for elt in it)` is slower than the tricky `[(yield from it)]`?
Shall I from now on replace the former by the latter in all of my scripts, or is there any drawbacks to using the `yield from` construct?

---

#### Edit

This is all related, so I don't feel like opening a new question, but this is getting even stranger.
I tried comparing `range(10)` and `[(yield from range(10))]`.

```
def f1():
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
    
def f2():
    for i in [(yield from range(10))]:
        print(i)

>>> timeit(f1, number=100000)
26.715589237537195

>>> timeit(f2, number=100000)
0.019948781941049987
```

So. Now, iterating over `[(yield from range(10))]` is 186 times as fast as iterating over a bare `range(10)`?

How do you explain why iterating over `[(yield from range(10))]` is so much faster than iterating over `range(10)`?

---

<sup>1: For the sceptical, the three expressions that follow do produce a `generator` object; try and call `type` on them.</sup>

Comment: "the best expression" how is "best expression" defined?

Comment: The first and the second have actually the same bytecode (except for the name of the object returned), etc.

Comment: @DeepSpace in terms of execution time and memory consumption especially, or any other criterion I might not be thinking of.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Not exactly, the first one loads a `<genexpr>` while the second loads a `<listcomp>`.

Comment: did they not say that this `yield from` abuse will be either patched or removed? I remember reading that somewhere. I might also be confusing it with something else.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Who? And how is it an abuse? If you happened to have a reference, I'd be glad to have a look at it.

Comment: @Rightleg [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32139977/6162307) is what i had in mind.

Comment: @Chris_Rands `timeit` tells me that `f3`, so the `yield from` variant, is `2.72` times as fast as the other two. What Python version are you using?

Comment: @Chris_Rands I added that info to my post. I ran with the default number of iterations and with more as well, and the result stays the same: `yield from` is faster.

Comment: @Rightleg You're right, my timings were off for other reasons, I can roughly replicate yours actually

Comment: @Chris_Rands This topic is really confusing me. How come a dedicated construct is slower than a somewhat contrived and counter intuitive one?

Comment: @Rightleg You must realize that your timings show only the time spent on creating/setting up the generator and not the time for running through/consuming the generator. IMHO, the latter is a more important performance characteristic of a generator.

Comment: @Leon I added that test to my post.

Comment: Can you add your results for just using `range`? I'm finding it slower to iterate through than the `yield from` trick.

Comment: @BallpointBen Is the **Edit** part what you want?

Comment: Whoops, thanks. That's... odd.

Comment: @Rightleg I don't think I can explain this, but I guess it would be worth checking this is a general phenomena and not some quirk of using the `range()` object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you should be doing:

```
g = (i for i in range(10))
```

It's a generator expression. It's equivalent to

```
def temp(outer):
    for i in outer:
        yield i
g = temp(range(10))
```

but if you just wanted an iterable with the elements of `range(10)`, you could have done

```
g = range(10)
```

You do not need to wrap any of this in a function.

If you're here to learn what code to write, you can stop reading. The rest of this post is a long and technical explanation of why the other code snippets are broken and should not be used, including an explanation of why your timings are broken too.

---

This:

```
g = [(yield i) for i in range(10)]
```

is a broken construct that should have been taken out years ago. 8 years after the problem was [originally reported](https://bugs.python.org/issue10544), the process to remove it is [finally beginning](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.7.html#deprecated). Don't do it.

While it's still in the language, on Python 3, it's equivalent to

```
def temp(outer):
    l = []
    for i in outer:
        l.append((yield i))
    return l
g = temp(range(10))
```

List comprehensions are supposed to return lists, but because of the `yield`, this one doesn't. It acts kind of like a generator expression, and it yields the same things as your first snippet, but it builds an unnecessary list and attaches it to the `StopIteration` raised at the end.

```
>>> g = [(yield i) for i in range(10)]
>>> [next(g) for i in range(10)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> next(g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration: [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

This is confusing and a waste of memory. Don't do it. (If you want to know where all those `None`s are coming from, read [PEP 342](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/).)

On Python 2, `g = [(yield i) for i in range(10)]` does something entirely different. Python 2 doesn't give list comprehensions their own scope - specifically list comprehensions, not dict or set comprehensions - so the `yield` is executed by whatever function contains this line. On Python 2, this:

```
def f():
    g = [(yield i) for i in range(10)]
```

is equivalent to

```
def f():
    temp = []
    for i in range(10):
        temp.append((yield i))
    g = temp
```

making `f` a generator-based coroutine, in the [pre-async sense](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/). Again, if your goal was to get a generator, you've wasted a bunch of time building a pointless list.

---

This:

```
g = [(yield from range(10))]
```

is silly, but none of the blame is on Python this time.

There is no comprehension or genexp here at all. The brackets are not a list comprehension; all the work is done by `yield from`, and then you build a 1-element list containing the (useless) return value of `yield from`. Your `f3`:

```
def f3():
    g = [(yield from range(10))]
```

when stripped of the unnecessary list-building, simplifies to

```
def f3():
    yield from range(10)
```

or, ignoring all the coroutine support stuff `yield from` does,

```
def f3():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i
```

---

Your timings are also broken.

In your first timing, `f1` and `f2` create generator objects that can be used inside those functions, though `f2`'s generator is weird. `f3` doesn't do that; `f3` *is* a generator function. `f3`'s body does not run in your timings, and if it did, its `g` would behave quite unlike the other functions' `g`s. A timing that would actually be comparable with `f1` and `f2` would be

```
def f4():
    g = f3()
```

In your second timing, `f2` doesn't actually run, for the same reason `f3` was broken in the previous timing. In your second timing, `f2` is not iterating over a generator. Instead, the `yield from` turns `f2` into a generator function itself.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> g = [(yield i) for i in range(10)]
> ```

This construct accumulates the data that is/may be passed back into the generator through its `send()` method and returns it via the `StopIteration` exception when the iteration is exhausted<sup>1</sup>:

```
>>> g = [(yield i) for i in range(3)]
>>> next(g)
0
>>> g.send('abc')
1
>>> g.send(123)
2
>>> g.send(4.5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration: ['abc', 123, 4.5]
>>> #          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

No such thing happens with plain generator comprehension:

```
>>> g = (i for i in range(3))
>>> next(g)
0
>>> g.send('abc')
1
>>> g.send(123)
2
>>> g.send(4.5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>>
```

As for the `yield from` version - in Python 3.5 (which I am using) it doesn't work outside functions, so the illustration is a little different:

```
>>> def f(): return [(yield from range(3))]
... 
>>> g = f()
>>> next(g)
0
>>> g.send(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in f
AttributeError: 'range_iterator' object has no attribute 'send'
```

OK, `send()` doesn't work for a generator `yield`ing `from` `range()` but let's at least see what's at the end of the iteration:

```
>>> g = f()
>>> next(g)
0
>>> next(g)
1
>>> next(g)
2
>>> next(g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration: [None]
>>> #          ^^^^^^
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that even if you don't use the `send()` method, `send(None)` is assumed, therefore a generator constructed in this way always uses more memory than plain generator comprehension (since it has to accumulate the results of the `yield` expression till the end of the iteration):

```
>>> g = [(yield i) for i in range(3)]
>>> next(g)
0
>>> next(g)
1
>>> next(g)
2
>>> next(g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration: [None, None, None]
```

---

**UPDATE**

Regarding the performance differences between the three variants. `yield from` beats the other two because it eliminates a level of indirection (which, to the best of my understanding, is one of the two main reasons why `yield from` was introduced). However, in this particular example `yield from` itself is superfluous - `g = [(yield from range(10))]` is actually almost identical to `g = range(10)`.

Comment: the `yield from` version works if you are inside a function

Comment: @Chris_Rands Thanks. Updated the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what conclusions to draw. the `yield from` variant accumulates `None` but only once, doesn't it? If so, I don't see any drawback to using that construct...

Answer (score 1):

This might not do what you think it does.

```
def f2():
    for i in [(yield from range(10))]:
        print(i)
```

Call it:

```
>>> def f2():
...     for i in [(yield from range(10))]:
...         print(i)
...
>>> f2() #Doesn't print.
<generator object f2 at 0x02C0DF00>
>>> set(f2()) #Prints `None`, because `(yield from range(10))` evaluates to `None`.
None
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

Because the `yield from` is not within a comprehension, it is bound to the `f2` function instead of an implicit function, turning `f2` into a generator function.

---

I remembered seeing someone point out that it was not actually iterating, but I can't remember where I saw that. I was testing the code myself when I rediscovered this. I didn't find the source searching through [the mailing list post](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-November/150678.html) nor the [bug tracker thread](https://bugs.python.org/issue10544). If someone finds the source, please tell me or add it to the post itself, so it can be credited.

Comment: I just removed a follow-up code oddity from my answer. Turns out there's special REPL handling for for-loops that I didn't know about, since I usually use IPython's REPL. The oddity has nothing to do with generators.