# Why is itertools.chain faster than a flattening list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-itertools, flatten

In the context of a discussion in the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49630581/why-does-python-forbid-the-use-of-sum-with-strings) it was mentioned that while concatenating a sequence of strings simply takes `''.join([str1, str2, ...])`, concatenating a sequence of lists would be something like `list(itertools.chain(lst1, lst2, ...))`, although you can also use a list comprehension like `[x for y in [lst1, lst2, ...] for x in y]`. What surprised me is that the first method is consistently faster than the second:

```
import random
import itertools

random.seed(100)
lsts = [[1] * random.randint(100, 1000) for i in range(1000)]

%timeit [x for y in lsts for x in y]
# 39.3 ms ± 436 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lsts))
# 30.6 ms ± 866 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit list(x for y in lsts for x in y)  # Proposed in comments
# 62.5 ms ± 504 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# Loop-based methods proposed in the comments
%%timeit
a = []
for lst in lsts: a += lst
# 26.4 ms ± 634 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%%timeit
a = []
for lst in lsts: a.extend(lst)
# 26.7 ms ± 728 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

It is not a difference of orders of magnitude, but it is not negligible either. I was wondering how that might be the case, since list comprehensions are frequently among the fastest methods to solve a given problem. At first I thought that maybe the `itertools.chain` object would have a `len` that the `list` constructor could use to preallocate the necessary memory, but that is not the case (cannot call `len` on `itertools.chain` objects). Is some custom `itertools.chain`-to-`list` conversion taking place somehow or is `itertools.chain` taking advantage of some other mechanism?

Tested in Python 3.6.3 on Windows 10 x64, if that is relevant.

*EDIT:*

It seems the fastest method after all is calling `.extend`ing an empty list with each list, as proposed by [@zwer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7553525/zwer), probably because it works on "chunks" of data instead of on a per-element basis.

Comment: What about `list(x for y in lsts for x in y)`?

Comment: @PeterWood Added it for comparison, seems even worse, which is also kind of surprising.

Comment: My guess is that the list comprehension has to do some expression evaluation in python space whereas the itertools variant isn't doing any expression evaluation (it's just yielding things entirely in C-space).

Comment: @mgilson You might be right, although if I change the number of lists the gap seems to scale. Ah wait, you mean expression evaluation on each iteration?

Comment: @jdehesa The [byte-code generated by LCs](https://ideone.com/zYcKZw) compared to functions that directly delegate to C makes a huge difference.

Comment: It would be useful if someone with C experience could dig into the difference. Could be something to do with memory allocation, but just a guess.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I see, so that's it then, it's just faster because it's in C? I really feel there should be a `[].join([lst1, lst2, ...])` syntax for lists (and maybe tuples), it's a rather common operation that most likely many developers are not implementing as well as it could be because it is kind of cumbersome (and a dedicated `join` method could probably do it even faster).

Comment: @jdehesa There were several propositions when this was being decided, [Guido chose `str.join` at the end](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/1999-June/095436.html).

Comment: If C-level detail isn't already provided elsewhere, I'll offer a bounty for a good answer. I have a vested interest: all too often I get shot down for using `chain.from_iterable` "..when you can do it without a library with nested so and so!"

Comment: @jpp Whoever is shooting you down for using itertools should check with a doctor :-P. With that said, it's basically a case of more code running at Python level vs C level. Chain's `next` method isn't doing anything special, it's just doing everything at C level: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c79fd57f86b6/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#l1846

Comment: Oh, by the way, related and still not answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45190729/differences-between-generator-comprehension-expressions

Comment: @jdehesa - While there isn't `[].join(...)` simple straight concatenation will still work. I'd even wager that it's faster than `itertools.chain()`, too.

Comment: @zwer What do you mean with "simple straight concatenation"? Just `+`/`sum`?

Comment: @jdehesa - Yep. Initiate an empty list `target = []` and then just flat extend it: `for x in lsts: target += x`. I can test it, but based on previous experiences I'm almost willing to bet it would outperform `itertools.chain()`. A bit more verbose, tho, but you can always write a `list_join()` function and stash it away to use instead of the _missing_ `[].join(...)`.

Comment: @zwer Just checked, looks about as fast as the list comprehension. As was suggested, I suppose it's just a matter of running more code in C than Python with `itertools`.

Comment: @jdehesa - That's weird, I just tested it and concatenation is consistently ~20% faster than `itertools.chain`, both on Python 2.7.14 and 3.5.1.

Comment: @zwer Huh, you're right, I run it again now and it looks like what you say, maybe something in the background affected the results earlier or something... I suppose this is the fastest because it works "per list", instead of "per element" (that's what I meant when I was saying a specialized `.join` method could be faster). Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is [itertools.chain.from_iterable](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/aa0735f597b072c0eb00404c4d7df359ddc26755/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L1854). It's not hard to read even if you don't know C and you can tell everything is happening at the c level (before being used to generate a list in your code).

The bytecode for list comprehensions is like so:

```
def f(lsts):
    return [x for y in lsts for x in y]

dis.dis(f.__code__.co_consts[1])
  2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                18 (to 24)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (y)
              8 LOAD_FAST                1 (y)
             10 GET_ITER
        >>   12 FOR_ITER                 8 (to 22)
             14 STORE_FAST               2 (x)
             16 LOAD_FAST                2 (x)
             18 LIST_APPEND              3
             20 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           12
        >>   22 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   24 RETURN_VALUE
```

These are all the python interpreter operations involved in creating a list comprehension. Just having all the operations at the C level (in `chain`) rather than having the interpreter step over each byte code step (in the comprehension) is what will give you that performance boost.

Still, that boost is so small I wouldn't worry about it. This is python, readability over speed.

---

Edit:

For a list wrapped generator comprehension

```
def g(lists):
    return list(x for y in lsts for x in y)

# the comprehension
dis.dis(g.__code__.co_consts[1])
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    2 FOR_ITER                20 (to 24)
              4 STORE_FAST               1 (y)
              6 LOAD_FAST                1 (y)
              8 GET_ITER
        >>   10 FOR_ITER                10 (to 22)
             12 STORE_FAST               2 (x)
             14 LOAD_FAST                2 (x)
             16 YIELD_VALUE
             18 POP_TOP
             20 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           10
        >>   22 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            2
        >>   24 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE
```

So the interpreter has a similar number of steps to go to in running the generator expression being unpacked by list, but as you would expect, the python level overhead of having `list` unpack a generator (as opposed to the C `LIST_APPEND` instruction) is what slows it down.

```
dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x000000000FB58B70, file "<ipython-input-33-1d46ced34d66>", line 2>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 ('f.<locals>.<listcomp>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (lsts)
              8 GET_ITER
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 RETURN_VALUE

dis.dis(g)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <genexpr> at 0x000000000FF6F420, file "<ipython-input-40-0334a7cdeb8f>", line 2>)
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 ('g.<locals>.<genexpr>')
              6 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              8 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (lsts)
             10 GET_ITER
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: That only explains why the first approach is way slower than the two other, but not why the `itertools.chain` approach is faster than the cast of a generator comprehension into a list, isn't it?

Comment: @Rightleg The list-wrapped generator comprehension was slower than both because a list comprehension is a c-optimised list-wrapped generator comprehension. (so many adjectives :/)

Comment: @FHTMitchell "list comprehension is a c-optimised list wrapped generator comprehension" is completely wrong. LCs don't create generator expression, it creates a list( check BUILD_LIST in your answer) and then populates it using special  `LIST_APPEND` bytecode that calls `PyList_Append`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary fair enough. I did know that, I suppose I was trying to simplify things. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I've updated the answer, since a simple for loop, as a user suggested, is actually faster than all the other options...

Comment: I think that's quite obvious. You're doing 1000 operations instead of 500 times that amount. You are also preallocating some of the memory as opposed to dynamically increasing it.