# Multiple yields in a generator expression? Python

Tags: python, generator, yield, generator-expression

I've been trying to convert this generator function into a generator expression, but with no success. Is it possible to have the same output with a generator expression?

```
    def gen5(num):
         for i in range(num):             
             yield i *2
             yield i *10
             yield i *i

    g = gen5(4) 
    list(g)
    [0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 1, 4, 20, 4, 6, 30, 9]
```

I've tried the following, but get this (None, None, None) output.

```
    gen_exp2 = (((yield u*2), (yield u*10) ,(yield u*u)) for u in  range(4))

    list(gen_exp2)

    [0,
     0,
     0,
     (None, None, None),
     2,
     10,
     1,
    (None, None, None),
     4,
    20,
     4,
    (None, None, None),
    6,
    30,
    9,
   (None, None, None)]
```

I've also done this, but it gives 4 nested tuples instead of the list above.

```
       gen_exp3 = (((i*2), (i*10), (i*i)) for i in range(4))

       list(gen_exp3)

       [(0, 0, 0), (2, 10, 1), (4, 20, 4), (6, 30, 9)]
```

Also, how can I add a parameter to a generator expression?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need the `yield` statements in a generator expression, surrounding the loop with parentheses is enough.

Comment: That doesn't generate the same output like the generator function. It gives  4 tuples.

Comment: You will need another nested for loop to "unpack" your tuples.

Comment: `(x for i in range(num) for x in (i*2, i*10, i*i))` works, but is confusing to read.  `itertools.chain.from_iterable((i*2, i*10, i*i) for i in range(num))` too

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Patrick. I thought for a moment that I couldn't convert a generator function into a gen expression.

Answer (score 3):

You just need a double loop in the gen exp:

```
num = 4
g = (j for i in range(num) for j in (i*2, i*10, i*i))
print(*g)
```

**output**

```
0 0 0 2 10 1 4 20 4 6 30 9
```

As Moses says, using `yield` in a gen exp is not a good idea.

---

Here's a cute variation, using `map`

```
g = (j for i in range(num) for j in map(i.__mul__, (2, 10, i)))
```

However, some people might not like that use of `i.__mul__`.

---

You asked: "How can I add a parameter to a generator expression?". Well, you can't. You *could* create a `lambda`, as Moses shows, but really you're better off making a proper generator function. Lambdas are supposed to be anonymous functions, so creating a lambda and binding it to a name is a rather dubious practice. ;)

Comment: @JonClements I suppose one could. It'd be interesting to know how it compares speed-wise to `i.__mul__`.

Comment: I'd be surprised if it wasn't slower because of additional function calls and lookups...

Comment: @JonClements Me too. OTOH, I guess `partial` could be using some tricky C magic to do its stuff. The CPython source for functools has a Python wrapper [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/functools.py#L230). I'm not having any luck trying to find the C source. Ah, [here we go](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_functoolsmodule.c)

Comment: My assumption would be that partial is somewhat slower because the `mul` indirection, and because it does need to make a 2-tuple for the arguments. I didn't try it yet though

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `yield` in a generator expression.

See [yield in list comprehensions and generator expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139885/yield-in-list-comprehensions-and-generator-expressions) on why this could easily be considered a bug, although it isn't.

You can use a **nested comprehension** to achieve the same thing in a generator expression:

```
gen_exp2 = (x for u in range(4) for x in (u*2, u*10, u*u))
```

And you can parameterise this by putting the generator expression in a function:

```
gen_fun = lambda num: (x for u in range(num) for x in (u*2, u*10, u*u))
```

Might be better to keep your original approach though, as using `yield` in a function may be faster than using a nested comprehension within a generator expression which is already pretty slow without nesting.

Comment: Understood your answer. Can you please provide the explanation for that output shown in the question? Just curious to know :)

Comment: @stack_n_queue Did you read the linked answer? Pretty much explains how the interpreter treats a `yield` in a gen. exp. and what happens behind the scenes: stack etc.