# What are the applications of yield within a comprehension or generator expression?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, yield, python-3.7

Python 3.7 documentation [mentions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr) that `yield` expressions are deprecated “in the implicitly nested scopes used to implement comprehensions and generator expressions”, with removal pending for 3.8:

> Due to their side effects on the containing scope, yield expressions are not permitted as part of the implicitly defined scopes used to implement comprehensions and generator expressions (in Python 3.7, such expressions emit DeprecationWarning when compiled, in Python 3.8+ they will emit SyntaxError).

I am trying to understand what this change affects (breaks?), because at first glance it addresses a rather esoteric scenario. Is there a good reason for having a `yield` within a list comprehension or a generator expression in the first place?

So far I came up with these (rather nonsensical) examples, which should be illegal in Python 3.8:

```
>>> list((yield i) for i in range(5))
[0, None, 1, None, 2, None, 3, None, 4, None]
>>> list([(yield i) for i in range(5)])
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I'm guessing this might be usable with generator-based coroutines, but you can't even assign within a comprehension to get the value sent with `send()`, like `(a = (yield) for i in ...)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [yield in list comprehensions and generator expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139885/yield-in-list-comprehensions-and-generator-expressions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What are the applications of yield within a comprehension or generator
>   expression?

Nothing.

This "feature" was confirmed to be a [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue10544) and is in the process of being deprecated for python3.7, and will be removed completely in python3.8, resulting in a `SyntaxError` if used.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html#deprecated),

> Yield expressions (both `yield` and `yield from` clauses) are now
>   deprecated in comprehensions and generator expressions (aside from the
>   iterable expression in the leftmost for clause). This ensures that
>   comprehensions always immediately return a container of the
>   appropriate type (rather than potentially returning a generator
>   iterator object), while generator expressions won’t attempt to
>   interleave their implicit output with the output from any explicit
>   yield expressions.
>
> In Python 3.7, such expressions emit `DeprecationWarning` when compiled,
>   in Python 3.8+ they will emit `SyntaxError`. (Contributed by Serhiy
>   Storchaka in bpo-10544.)

Comment: I'm afraid this answer doesn't help much. I know that this feature is being deprecated, I'm trying to understand *what* the feature actually is.

Comment: I would still be curious to understand how Python was interpreting the code examples in the OP's question... I would expect this behavior to be a "high level" bug, not just a typo in the code.