# Why is one generator faster than other with `yield` inside?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, generator, bytecode

I have two functions returning generator:

```
def f1():
    return (i for i in range(1000))

def f2():
    return ((yield i) for i in range(1000))
```

Apparently, generator returned from `f2()` is twice as slower than `f1()`:

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import timeit, dis
>>> timeit.timeit("list(f1())", globals=globals(), number=1000)
0.057948426001530606
>>> timeit.timeit("list(f2())", globals=globals(), number=1000)
0.09769760200288147
```

I tried to using dis to see what's going on but to no avail:

```
>>> dis.dis(f1)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <genexpr> at 0x7ffff7ec6d20, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 ('f1.<locals>.<genexpr>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              8 LOAD_CONST               3 (1000)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(f2)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <genexpr> at 0x7ffff67a25d0, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 ('f2.<locals>.<genexpr>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              8 LOAD_CONST               3 (1000)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

Apparently, the results from `dis` are the same.

So why is generator returned from `f1()` faster than generator from `f2()`? And what is proper way to debug this? Apparently `dis` in this case fails.

**EDIT 1:**

Using `next()` instead of `list()` in timeit reverses the results (or they are the same in some cases):

```
>>> timeit.timeit("next(f1())", globals=globals(), number=10**6)
1.0030477920008707
>>> timeit.timeit("next(f2())", globals=globals(), number=10**6)
0.9416838550023385
```

**EDIT 2:**

Apparently it's bug in Python, fixed in 3.8. See [yield in list comprehensions and generator expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139885/yield-in-list-comprehensions-and-generator-expressions)

Generator with yield inside actually yields two values.

Comment: doing `next(f1())` instead of `list(f1())` for instance [reverses the results](https://repl.it/repls/DenseTalkativeApplicationprogrammer). It is not only how the `f()`s are setup, but also what you do with them.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis yes, doing `timeit.timeit("next(f1())", globals=globals(), number=10**7)` is slower than using f2(). Interesting...

Comment: Because `(yield i)` is converted to `YIELD_VALUE` opcode and parsing the syntax plus pushing/poping that opcode to stack will take more time. And the reason you can't see that is because generator-expressions are converted to generator functions and `dis` doesn't give a nested disassembled representation of the bytecodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yield in generator expressions is actually a bug, as discussed in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139885/yield-in-list-comprehensions-and-generator-expressions).

If you want to actually see what's going on with dis, you need to introspect on the code object's `co_const[0]`, so:

```
>>> dis.dis(f1.__code__.co_consts[1])
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    3 FOR_ITER                11 (to 17)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
              9 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             12 YIELD_VALUE
             13 POP_TOP
             14 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
        >>   17 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(f2.__code__.co_consts[1])
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    3 FOR_ITER                12 (to 18)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
              9 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             12 YIELD_VALUE
             13 YIELD_VALUE
             14 POP_TOP
             15 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
        >>   18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             21 RETURN_VALUE
```

So, it yields twice.

Comment: Ok, now I see. I'm using Python 3.6 so it yields twice.

Comment: I would not call it a bug. Doc. from Python 3.6 says at *6.2.9. Yield expressions* that it is the expected behaviour: *The value of the yield expression after resuming depends on the method which resumed the execution. If `__next__()` is used (typically via either a `for` or the `next()` builtin) then the result is `None`...*. As it is assumed not to be what the *progammer* expected, `yield(yield ...)` is deprecated in 3.7 and a syntax error in 3.8. But it is not a Python bug (at most a program one).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is because the generator returned by `f2` returns twice the number of elements.

Just look what happens:

```
>>> def f2():
    return ((yield i) for i in range(10))
>>> g = f2()
>>> print([i for i in g])
[0, None, 1, None, 2, None, 3, None, 4, None, 5, None, 6, None, 7, None, 8, None, 9, None]
```

Using `yield` in a generator returns a `None` element after each actual item.

Comment: Is this a bug or feature?

Comment: @AndrejKesely this is a bug, that is going to be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Your formulation of `f2()` is the first thing that stroke me as *unusual*. Writing `f2()` the way most people would yields (pun intended) very different results:

```
import timeit

def f1():
    return (i for i in range(1000))

def f2():
    for i in range(1000):
        yield i

res1 = timeit.timeit("list(f1())", globals=globals(), number=1000)
print(res1)  # 0.05318646361085916
res2 = timeit.timeit("list(f2())", globals=globals(), number=1000)
print(res2)  # 0.05284952304875785
```

So the two seem to be equally fast.

As others say in their answers, this probably has to do with the fact that your `f2()` returns twice as many elements.